# How to format a string multiple times with different integers?

Tags: c#, integer

So here's my problem, basically I'm reading the last few lines after a keyword ('#Footer' in my case) of a number of datafiles and only extracting relevant data, I'm able to extract the end of a file, but have an issue when reading multiple ones,

Say I've got some example files, 'testfile00', 'testfile21', 'testfile 10' etc

Keep in mind I'm not particularly experienced in any sort of programming, how would I go about reading these files and extracting the data from them?

I've got the following code so far;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

                string str1 = @"C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\testfile";
                string str2 = i.ToString();
                string str3 = ".datafile";

                string final = str1 + str2 + str2 + str3;


                var lines = File.ReadLines(final)
                            .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("#Footer"))
                            .Skip(1)
                            .ToList();

                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));


        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I know this is wrong using the 'str2 + str2', the results I get will only read the files, 'testfile00', 'testfile11' and 'testfile22', this is where I'm not sure how to correct this to get the files with 01, 12, 20 etc. any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Display the results of both `str2.ToString()` and `str2.ToString() + str2.ToString()` in the console and you'll see what you are actually doing.

Comment: You can also use Path.Combine to combine multiple strings in a full path

Answer (score 2):

I think an easier approach would be:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, "*.datafile"))
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(file)
                    .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("#Footer"))
                    .Skip(1)
                    .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
}
```

where `yourPath` in this case is `C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\`

Comment: You can also pass a search pattern to GetFiles to filter the filenames

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you can; but it's tricky. There are some very big caveats, and they specifically surround three character extensions. However, that discussion is probably outside the scope of this post, so I digress. The OP could potentially pass in the extension `datafile` as it appears they end in that so I'll update for that.

Comment: You wouldn't find the same set of files that OP's parsing with your `GetFiles`. The search criteria is too broad, since all the files OP is parsing has a name that starts with `testfile` and an extension of `datafile`

Comment: @RuneFS, I'd find all files with an extension of `datafile`; what does `testfile` have to do with it?

Comment: `str1 + str2 + str2 + str3`is the file path and str1 ends in testfile so if `i`is one the full path would be `c:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\testfile11.datafile` Ie the file name is `testfile11.datafile` however if there's a file called `productionfile11.datafile` in what ever `yourPath` refers to you'd pick that one up but OP wouldn't

Comment: @RuneFS, I'm pretty sure there isn't near enough information in this question to start going down the *what if* road. Second, clearly the OP is just testing this stuff; your *what if* scenario is pretty much almost unlikely.

Comment: I find that very often the files I'm looking for when I need to parse them have a very specific name or name pattern. So in my work highly likely but also irrelevant to the poibnt that your code does something different from what OP is doing. **HOWEVER** I do like the simplicity of the code

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested loop

```
try
{
    string str1 = @"C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\testfile";
    string str3 = ".datafile";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j< 3; j++){               

            string final = str1 + i+ j + str3;


            var lines = File.ReadLines(final)
                        .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("#Footer"))
                        .Skip(1)
                        .ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
        }

    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.Read();
}
```

However you might want to make sure the file exist before you try to read it and you also might wish to make it more declarative since that's usually easier to read. (When to get the hang of the syntax). The human mind is **a lot** better at reading/understanding something that's sequential than it is executing a loop

```
var path = @"C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\testfile";
var ext  = ".datafile";
var range = Enumerable.Range(0,3);
var filePaths = 
             from i in range
             from j in range
             let file = path + i + j+ ext
             where File.Exists(file)
             select File.ReadLines(f)
                        .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("#Footer"))
                        .Skip(1);
try{
   Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,filePaths.SelectMany(f => f));
} catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.Read();
}
```

**EDIT** It would seem from your comment that the files your are talking about are not named in a consequtive way in that case it's probably better to something similar to [Michaels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19930407/112407)

Essentially you'd need to replace the first 3 lines from the LINQ statement above above

```
      var filePaths = 
             //This will go through all files in the directory but can be narrowed
             //down if needed ie if not all files should be parsed
             from i in Directory.GetFiles(path)
             //You don't need to test if the files exist any more
             select File.ReadLines(f)
                        .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("#Footer"))
                        .Skip(1);
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! Say now if I wanted to read a file with this format, 131502_091232_testfile, where it contains the year, month, day, then hour, minute, second. (obviously I'd have to rearrange var path, ext and so on)

Comment: That depends on how you wish to search for the files? Are these data and times consequetive and if so with which interval or are they all located in one directory and if so can it be assumed that all files in that dir should be read or just some of them?